# MongoError: Can't extract geo keys

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geonear

I'm facing a mongoose error during post data updation. 
The error is:

> MongoError: Can't extract geo keys

I've tried to find the reason and the solution by searching on google but still I didn't get any proper solution.

**Posts Model**

```
const geoLocationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: { type: String, default: 'Point'},
    coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
        index: { type: '2dsphere', sparse: false },
    }
});

const postsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    post_title: String,
    geoLocation: geoLocationSchema,
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

**Post Controller**

```
const Posts = require("../models/Posts");

var findPattern = {_id: "5e8c661f274e8e57d8e03887"}; 
var updatePattern = {   geoLocation: {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [-8.4556973, 114.5110151] }
};

Posts.updateOne(findPattern, updatePattern) .then(updateRes => {
    console.log("post updated"); 
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("error", err.toString()); 
});
```

**Output is:**

> MongoError: Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('5e8c661f274e8e57d8e03887'), geoLocation: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -8.455697300000001, 114.5110151 ], _id: ObjectId('5e8d7f7c35b9d36d45b483a2') } }  can't project geometry into spherical CRS: [ -8.455697300000001, 114.5110151 ]

Comment: check your lat lang value, they seems out of range.

Comment: @mehta-rohan Lat long are correct. It's for Bali, Indonesia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a field named coordinates that specifies the object’s coordinates.

If specifying latitude and longitude coordinates, list the longitude first and then latitude:

Valid longitude values are between -180 and 180, both inclusive.
Valid latitude values are between -90 and 90, both inclusive.

Which means this takes longitude at index 0 and latitude at index 1.

Try `coordinates: [ 114.5110151,-8.4556973] }`

Comment: Thank you Rohan. I implemented it in my code. One more thing I want to ask to you Is there any other kind of logic needs to be implemented for latitude and longitude as you said Valid longitude values are between -180 and 180, both inclusive. Valid latitude values are between -90 and 90, both inclusive?

Comment: If you are picking these values from sensors then you don't need to worry much, except you can have simple range  checks in place.

Answer (score 1):

[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyQcE.png)

Note:
userSchema.index({ location: '2dsphere' })

Comment: Please post your code directly to the post, no need of adding extra URLs that can become invalid in future.